# MySQL: Custom row validation

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have such example:

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES a(id)
);

DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER a_insert BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '01431' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The foreign data source you are trying to reference does not exist.';
END;;

DELIMITER ;


INSERT INTO a(parent_id) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO a(parent_id) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO a(parent_id) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO a(parent_id) VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO a(parent_id) VALUES (999);

SELECT * FROM a
```

This end up with 4 recods:

```
----------------
id     parent_id
----------------
1      NULL
2      1
3      2
4      4
```

I found post online that MySQL does not support rollbacks in triggers. That is a problem because I want such hierarchy where no row points to it self and inserts like the one with `ID=4` works just fine. How do I ensure there are no such records in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is with `auto_increment`, because you in `BEFORE INSERT` event you don't have that value assigned yet. On the other hand in `AFTER INSERT` event you can't do anything with it.

If you want to use `auto_increment` id column a possible solution is to use separate table for sequencing.

Your schema would look like

```
CREATE TABLE a_seq(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE a(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 0,
  parent_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES a(id)
);
```

And your trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER a_insert 
BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO a_seq VALUES(NULL);
  SET NEW.id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  IF NEW.id = NEW.parent_id THEN
    SET NEW.id = NULL;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*If `id=parent_id` the trigger deliberately violates `NOT NULL` constraint assigning NULL value. Therefore this record won't be inserted.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17181/2)** demo. Uncomment last insert statement. It won't allow you to make such insert.

Comment: Too bad this requires 2 tables but it's definitely an answer. Thank you.